# How can I check the status of a pytest process?

Tags: process, python, ps

I was thinking of putting this question in StackOverflow since it deals with Pytest, but it is actually more of a linux question so I put it here.

I am running pytest tests on linux (ubuntu),with `python -m pytest`  and I have started running a test that takes a long time to complete. So when I run the test (from the terminal of course), the terminal just stays there, waiting for it to complete (no output until it finishes).

My question is how can I check its status?

I have tried using `ps` but frankly I don't know how to interpret its results. Some of them say "Python" but I don't know how to identify which process refers to the one I am running.

Any help is  welcomed

Comment: Add the command that you are running to your question.

Comment: What is it you expect to have as status? One thing is "running/blocked" another is "80% completed".

Comment: @NasirRiley it is right there: `ps`

Comment: @EduardoTrápani First I want to identify which is the process that I am running

Comment: The command that your are running with Pytest, not `ps`.

Comment: I added it to the question